# How to make apex:selectradio display options in a two-column table?

Tags: apex, visualforce, html, selectradio

I have a group of radio buttons that display like A, but I need it to display like B.

Currently my code is:

```
<apex:selectRadio styleClass="w-100" value="{!selectedValue}" layout="pageDirection">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!values}"></apex:selectOptions>
    <apex:actionSupport action="{!randomAction}" event="onchange" reRender="randomDiv" oncomplete="RunScript();"/>
</apex:selectRadio>
```

I tried diving the selectedValue list into two lists, one for even numbers and another one for odd numbers, but it wasn't working either, maybe because both had the same value="{!selectedValue}"?

[image: Currently displays like A, but I need it to display like B]

Answer (score 0):

@gyau The below code should work the way you wanted. Btw, i used country names but feel free to change the code you want. The below code will work for both layout direction `pageDirection` and `lineDirection`.

Let me know if it helps!

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page controller="sampleCon" name="VFSelectRadioPage">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var td = $(".apexSelectRadio td");
            td.each(function(i){
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    td.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll('<tr/>')
                }
            }).parent('tr').unwrap();
        });
    </script>
    <apex:form id="radioOptionsForm">
        <apex:selectRadio value="{!country}" layout="lineDirection" id="radioOptions" styleClass="apexSelectRadio">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
        </apex:selectRadio>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex controller:

```
public class sampleCon {
    String country = null;
         
    public PageReference test() {
        return null;
    }
                
    public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>(); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('India','India')); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('Australia','Australia')); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('Singapore','Singapore')); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('New Zealand','New Zealand')); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('Malaysia','Malaysia')); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('Indonesia','Indonesia')); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('Canada','Canada')); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('Mexico','Mexico')); return options; 
    }
                   
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
                    
    public void setCountry(String country) { this.country = country; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Yesterday I ended up using layout="pageDirection" and using CSS. I will post my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the following code:

Visualforce:

```
<apex:selectRadio styleClass="w-100 formatTable" value="{!selectedValue}" layout="pageDirection">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!values}"></apex:selectOptions>
    <apex:actionSupport action="{!randomAction}" event="onchange" reRender="randomDiv" oncomplete="RunScript();"/>
</apex:selectRadio>
```

The *w-100 class* in the Visualforce code comes from bootstrap. It's equivalent to *width: 100%*

CSS:

```
.formatTable tr{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50% ;
    padding: 2px 0;
}
            
.formatTable td{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Did not know that you were planning to use bootstrap. Thanks for letting me know. Good luck!